# Mysql keeps on restarting and shutdown in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

```
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.367975Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.369624Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 1 ...
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.372921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.372942Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.372947Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.372952Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.372968Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.372972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.373291Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.373432Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.375506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.388608Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.391222Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.403447Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.474527Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.474621Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.680361Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.682461Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.682498Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.683937Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 13805196
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.685254Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.685303Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.690345Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200908  2:05:23
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.696899Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.696919Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.697738Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.697786Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.698319Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.698458Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.698525Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.698560Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.736220Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.737779Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.737819Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738067Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
my-admin-db.com_1       | 
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738146Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738271Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738288Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738298Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738308Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738316Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738539Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738553Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738589Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738711Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738934Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738975Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738984Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.738992Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739000Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739008Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739017Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739025Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739042Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739052Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739060Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739069Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739078Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739087Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739095Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739104Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739113Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739121Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739129Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739137Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739146Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739154Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739162Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739171Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739180Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739189Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739197Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739377Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.739810Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.840672Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.841296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200908  2:05:23
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.509915Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 13805215
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.511721Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.511744Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.511751Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.511757Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.511761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.511935Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:25.512173Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**This is my docker compose yml file.**

```
version: '2'
services:
  my-admin-db.com:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes_from:
      - my-admin-db-data.com
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      TZ: "US/Eastern"
      JAVA_OPTS: -Xms128m
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    restart: always 
    mem_limit: 512m
  my-admin-db-data.com:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/mysql/my_admin:/var/lib/mysql

  my-db.com:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes_from:
      - my-db-data.com
    environment:
      TZ: "US/Eastern"
      JAVA_OPTS: -Xms128m
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    ports:
      - "3352:3306"
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 512m
  my-db-data.com:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/mysql/my_db:/var/lib/mysql
```

I have two mysql instance in my docker yml. One is working fine while another is creating error. I have also tried to change the mysql port and removing the existing container but still it is giving me same error.

It looks like the error coming from here

```
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
my-admin-db.com_1       | 2020-09-08T06:05:23.737819Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
```

But I am not able to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

adding below statement in .yml file will work

```
command: "--skip-grant-tables"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a permission thing.

```
~/docker/mysql/my_admin
~/docker/mysql/my_db
```

- Did you check folders for permissions?
- Did they created by docker-compose itself, or by hand?
- Did you try from scratch, without any data or
  folder?

Comment: I guess not, if that happened than my both mysql instance would be creating issue. But in my case  my-db.com instance is working fine